# Difference between uses for function name and rule of assignment

Tags: functions, notation

My professor has defined a function $f$  in class as an ordered triple $(S, T, $f$)$, where $S = $ Source, $T =$ Target, and f = the rule of assignment. Because the rule of assignment shares the same letter as the function name (albeit a different font), things have gotten very confusing.

My question is, Where is the rule of assignment used, and where is the function name used?

My teacher has told me that the function call uses the variable for the rule of assignment instead of the function name, so it's f$(x)$ and not $f(x)$.

He has also told me that the rule of assignment is used for determining ordered pairs that belong to the function. (EX: $(x, y) \in $ f vs. $(x, y) \in f$).

The first idea seems false, while the latter seems true. Could you help clear this up for me?

Comment: What "seems false" about the first statement to you?

Comment: @EricWofsey It doesn't seem right that a member of the function would be the thing that is being called. Usually if you were to define a function to do a certain behavior on a certain input, you would refer to the function in whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, actually, virtually no one ever distinguishes between f and $f$.  Everyone just writes them with the same symbol.  This is ambiguous in theory, but in practice there is almost never any risk of confusion.

So I wouldn't worry about it.  Just follow whatever rules your professor says for your class; outside of this particular class you will probably never need to follow them again.  Your professor's rules are not standard, universally accepted rules, but rather rules which he probably made up himself just to emphasize the distinction in your course.